# How to code many to many relationship in PERL?

Tags: perl

I have logs that I need to parse that have source and destination IP addresses. 
I'd like to store the source IP and destination IP as a pair of values as I iterate through the log.

I tried a hash, it didn't work. Here is an example of the problem:

```
%sessionIPs = ();

$sessionIPs{"1.1.1.1"} = "2.2.2.2";
$sessionIPs{"1.1.1.2"} = "3.3.3.3";
$sessionIPs{"1.1.1.3"} = "4.4.4.4";
$sessionIPs{"1.1.1.1"} = "5.5.5.5";
$sessionIPs{"3.3.3.3"} = "6.6.6.6";

foreach my $key ( keys %sessionIPs )
{
        print "key: $key, value: $sessionIPs{$key}\n";
}

#prints
key: 1.1.1.3, value: 4.4.4.4
key: 1.1.1.2, value: 3.3.3.3
key: 1.1.1.1, value: 5.5.5.5
key: 3.3.3.3, value: 6.6.6.6
```

As you can tell, I lost the 1.1.1.1 source IP and 2.2.2.2 destination IP key / value pair because a hash requires a unique key. I need a hash or other type of object that doesn't prohibit duplicate keys.

What object in perl allows me to store this kind of related data?

Comment: You would need a hash where the value is an **array**, not a **scalar**. Alternatively, you could append to the value, rather than replacing it, seperating the IP addressed in the value with a character of your choice, such as a comma or semi-colon.

Comment: Data structure design is much more about what *questions* you want to ask, rather than how you imagine the data's structure. Are these source and destination addresses always distinct, or is the relationship mostly symmetrical? (Can a destination also be a source?) What information do you want to know for any given address? For instance, counts of outgoing connections, whether an address is a source or a destination, how many times a given source-destination pair has connected in a given period etc.

Comment: What you want is actually 1:N (each key has many values), not N:N. As such, a hash of arrays will do.

Comment: From your description you only need a one-to-many relationship, but the details depend on what you need to know. A hash of hashes will tell you whether a given pair of addresses was ever connected, and how many times. A hash of arrays will keep the connections *from* a source address in order, if that matters. And so on. You need to think about what access you need, and you should consider using a database

Comment: All of your responses are excellent. I seems I do need a hash of arrays, and I do need to think more about the questions I need to answer. Right now I need to answer questions like "What are the Top 3 destinations", and "what source IPs are going to those top 3". When I saw the second question, I immediately thought store both source and destination IP as a related pair.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are on the right track, I think a hash is a good way to go. However, rather than storing a scalar (single value) in the hash, you could store an array of values inside the hash:

```
%sessionIPs = {};
@{$sessionIPs{"1.1.1.1"}} = ("2.2.2.2", "5.5.5.5");
...
```

Of course, you'll likely want to add destinations programmatically, so you could push new values:

```
push @{$sessionIPs{"1.1.1.1"}}, "6.6.6.6";
```

or, more generically:

```
push @{$sessionIPs{$source}}, $destination;
```

A complete example:

```
%sessionIPs = ();

push @{ $sessionIPs{"1.1.1.1"}}, "2.2.2.2";
push @{ $sessionIPs{"1.1.1.1"}}, "3.3.3.3";
push @{ $sessionIPs{"1.1.1.1"}}, "4.4.4.4";
push @{ $sessionIPs{"5.5.5.5"}}, "6.6.6.6";
push @{ $sessionIPs{"5.5.5.5"}}, "7.7.7.7";

foreach my $source ( keys %sessionIPs ) {
        print "source: $source\n";
        foreach my $dest ( @{$sessionIPs{$source}} ) {
                print "  dest: $dest\n";
        }
}
```

provides the output:

```
source: 1.1.1.1
  dest: 2.2.2.2
  dest: 3.3.3.3
  dest: 4.4.4.4
source: 5.5.5.5
  dest: 6.6.6.6
  dest: 7.7.7.7
```

Comment: I would probably write that as `$sessionIPs{"1.1.1.1"} = [ "2.2.2.2", "5.5.5.5" ];` as I think it clearer.

Comment: @KRichardson That seems to be the solution some of the others were talking about in the comments above, I tried it and it will work! Many thanks.  Thanks also to Sobrique for that little tidbit. I understood KRichardsons solution but it was even more clear after reading your post.

Comment: I'm not having any success searching the hash of arrays for defined values. Here is a sample question. "Which source IPs have a destination IP of x.x.x.x". So I need to query the array within the hash, and I don't have any code because I'm not quite sure how to start that. Should I open a new question for this too?

Comment: That is a different can of worms, but the basic method I would use is similar to the output (nested foreach loops). Outside the outer loop initialize an empty hash `%sourcesFound` or something similar. Then inside the inner loop put in a check like `if ($dest eq $searchDest) $sourcesFound{$key} = 1;` After this, `keys %sourcesFound` would contain all sources that contain the requested destination.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give that a go and see how far I get, its not easy so far. Hopefully I get something to work soon.